# I can't tell the difference between an accepted and unaccepted answer

Tags: feature-request, design

Perhaps I'm just color-blind, but for me it is impossible to tell the difference between the **accepted** and **not accepted** checkmarks next to answers to my questions:

[image: StackExchange Christiantity - Cannot see the difference between accepted and not accepted]

Even when they are right next to each other, the difference between the two is faint. Instead, I have to hover over the checkmark, deducing which state the answer is in based on the hover text.

Would it be possible to make the grey more faded, or the green more green? Perhaps even use a blue checkmark, the same color as used by the "upvote" button?

Comment: This looks related, but was asked back when the site was using the default Beta template: [_StackExchange Christianity Meta: The accept answer icon_](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/the-accept-answer-icon)

Comment: Strange. I can see green as green and gray as gray. Maybe it's my computer monitor or the fact that I am ***not*** color-blind.

Comment: Can you see the blue-colored up arrow compared to the gray down arrow?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm green/blue colorblind, so that may be it. I can see the difference between that light blue up arrow and green, but some shades of blue/green are harder for me to differentiate.

Comment: @Matt I haven't downovted on this site yet; for one, I haven't found a question/answer worthy of it, and second, I still need 2 more rep for downvoting privileges.

Comment: I'm not referring to downvotes. It is gray by default.

Comment: @Matt Oh, now I see what you mean. Yes, the difference between the blue up-arrow and the grey down-arrow is _very_ clear for me.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously the contrast here isn't black and white and you are not the first to suggest a little more contrast. Perhaps we can get SE to spend a  few minutes darkening things up.

Or the other hand, the icons in question are not nearly as subtle as as you describe either. I can tell the difference on main from across the room without even looking carefully.*

It sounds like the gamma correction on your monitor may be seriously out of whack. Have you considered color calibrating your screen so that you see things the way they were meant to be seen? This will make much more than just this website work better, you may find there is a whole range of design features you are missing out on across the web and your other software.

<sub>* Icon shading on meta, on the other hand, really *is* subtle.</sub>